# unable to connect to a running jupyter notebook on jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am unable to connect to a long-running jupyter notebook running inside my jupyter-lab. The lab server is running locally on my laptop.

The browser which was connected to the server crashed for some odd reason. But the notebook kept running as it should. Hence, I should be able to connect to the running notebook on the server. But when I attempt to connect the console on the jupyter-lab server gives a blank screen and i can see some 404 errors in the server logs. not sure what it means and how to recover from it.

If I have to kill the lab server, I will have to repeat my 5day long experiment all over again. Any help is appreciated. For more clarity I am on a Mac, had initially connected to the lab server using Brave browser(it is a Chrome clone), lab server is running on iTerm. I have tried switching browsers but I am still unable to connect to the notebook. The notebook continues to run as I can see from the selenium-webriver opening firefox instances.

logs on the jupyter-lab server

```
[I 13:12:18.610 LabApp] 302 POST /login?next=%2Flab%3F (::1) 1.88ms
[I 13:12:18.615 LabApp] 302 GET / (::1) 0.50ms
[W 13:12:18.636 LabApp] 404 GET /main.ede7b15ba64ec4b33ae5.js (::1) 1.96ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab?
[W 13:12:18.640 LabApp] 404 GET /vendors~main.5f0ef20c1b446f440307.js (::1) 2.26ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab?
[I 13:16:34.491 LabApp] 302 GET / (::1) 0.89ms
[W 13:16:34.552 LabApp] 404 GET /main.ede7b15ba64ec4b33ae5.js (::1) 3.46ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab?
[W 13:16:34.554 LabApp] 404 GET /vendors~main.5f0ef20c1b446f440307.js (::1) 4.19ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab?
```

Answer (score 0):

after a while, I figured how to fix this issue. I force re-installed the particular version of Jupyterlab and that did the trick.